# K-means clustering algorithm in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I was looking for the *k-means clustering* algorithm in TensorFlow. Does anyone know if TensorFlow has support for it?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have it: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeansClustering.

It may also be helpful: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeans.

Note that all code under [`tf.contrib`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib) is volatile or experimental. Furthermore, note that you could easily have found what I did using the [search box](https://www.tensorflow.org/s/results/?q=k-means&p=%2F) in the TensorFlow website.

Comment: Will that be good idea to use contrib api in production ? As I understand Estimators are much evolved version as compare to contrib.

Comment: @Shashi This is should probably be another question.